# \DeclareMathOperator won't take arguments

Tags: math-mode, macros, amsmath

I'd like to define a family of math operators that have the same superscript, but different subscripts. My first attempt was:

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\Upd}[1]{U^M_{#1}}
```

But the log tells me that:

```
l.3 \DeclareMathOperator{\Upd}[1
                                ]{U^M_{#1}}
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.3 \DeclareMathOperator{\Upd}[1]{U^
                                    M_{#1}}
! You can't use `macro parameter character #' in math mode.
l.3 \DeclareMathOperator{\Upd}[1]{U^M_{#
                                        1}}
! Extra }, or forgotten $.
l.3 \DeclareMathOperator{\Upd}[1]{U^M_{#1}}
```

This is a kind of work-around, but not ideal.

```
\newcommand\UPD[1]{\mathop{\mathrm{U}^\mathrm{M}_\mathrm{#1}}}
```

Is there a way to make `\DeclareMathOperator` take arguments or am I stuck with the work around?

Comment: I think the intent of `DeclareMathOperator` is to make something like `sin`, `exp`, etc. As far as I can remember there are no math operators of this kind (roman with stuff in brackets to the right) that take arguments.

Comment: Also, my favourite operator to define is `\newcommand{\expup}[1]{mathrm{e}^{#1}}`.

Comment: Typo. That should have been `\newcommand{\expup}[1]{\mathrm{e}^{#1}}`.

Comment: See my updated answer for the problems with the upright M.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The better way to use such a construction is to say

```
\newcommand{\Upd}{\operatorname{U}^{\mathrm{M}}}
```

Then one can use `\Upd_{1}` which is not harder to write than `\Upd{1}` that would be allowed by `\newcommand{\Upd}{\operatorname{U}^{\mathrm{M}}_{#1}}`.

Of course, putting in `\ensuremath` will break things, but it's unnecessary. Besides

```
$\Upd_{1}$
```

is clearer an input than `\Upd{1}`.

The command `\operatorname{U}` is just a wrapper around `\mathop{<font setup>U}\nolimits`, where `<font setup>` are some instructions that are irrelevant for this discussion. When one says

```
\mathop{<f>}\nolimits^{<a>}_{<b>}
```

where `<f>`, `<a>` and `<b>` are any subformulas, TeX treats *the whole block* as a math operator, as far a spacing is concerned. So, with my recommended definition, the input `\Upd_{1}` will eventually become

```
\mathop{<font setup>U}\nolimits^{\mathrm{M}}_{1}
```

that will work as a math operator. There is no need to push the superscript or the subscript inside `\mathop`. This is common: when one writes `$a=_{t}b$`, the whole `=_{t}` will be treated as a relation symbol, with the correct spacing around it.

Technically, `\mathop{<f>}` builds the subformula `<f>` and assigns it as the main field of a MathOp atom; each math atom has two other fields, for the superscript and the subscript, which, if present, don't affect the type of the atom.

Finally, `\DeclareMathOperator` and `\operatorname` should not be thought as ways to get upright letters; an upright letter is obtained by `\mathrm`; it's true that those two commands write their argument in upright letters, but the main thing they do is to prepare for correct spacing.

The `\nolimits` command is omitted when `\operatorname*` is used, but this is a different topic.

Comment: So does `\DeclareMathOperator` do anything apart from apply `\operatorname` to its argument? That is, will I ever see a difference between the two outputs?

Comment: @Seamus `\DeclareMathOperator{\xyz}{xyz}` is only more efficient than `\newcommand{\xyz}{\operatorname{xyz}}`: the final result will be exactly the same.

Answer (score 20):

To introduce an argument, you could combine defining the operator and your command:

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\UpdOp}{U}
\newcommand\Upd[1]{\UpdOp^M_{#1}}
```

That's also possible with the starred version instead

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\UpdOp}{U}
```

resulting in `\Upd` having the superscript and subscript on the right in inline math mode, and above and below in displayed math mode.

I assume, you would like to have M in operatorfont as well. So, why not defining operators and your command:

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\UpdOp}{U}
\DeclareMathOperator{\MOp}{M}
\newcommand\Upd[1]{\UpdOp^{\MOp}_{#1}}
```

Also here you can used the starred version, here the output how it can look inline and displayed:

[image: operators with argument for subscript]

Shorter, as discussed in the comments:

```
\newcommand{\Upd}{\operatorname{U}^{\operatorname{M}}}
```

`\operatorname{U^M}` instead would result in wrong subscript spacing.

With the subscript in operator font too, this would get longer but Boris showed a short working version, here slightly modified:

```
\newcommand{\Upd}[1]{\operatorname{U^M_{#1}}}
```

Or combine starred `\DeclareMathOperator` with operator font super- and subscript and automatically adjusted limits for the main operator:

```
\DeclareMathOperator*{\UpdOp}{U}
\newcommand\Upd[1]{\UpdOp^{\operatorname{M}}_{\operatorname{#1}}}
```

Comment: On the other hand, `\Upd_{x}` is not that harder to write, so `\newcommand{\Upd}{\operatorname{U}^M}` would be easier.

Comment: @egreg but if `\Upd` has a superscript, then having the subscript outside messes with the spacing because of grouping. It ends up looking like: `{U^M}_X` which doesn't look good. That's why I wanted an operator.

Comment: @Seamus There's no grouping!

Comment: @egreg there is grouping if you use `\mathop` which I want to use, for the spacing.

Comment: @Seamus `\mathop{...}^{...}` still retains its math operator status: the subscripts and superscripts are attached as fields to the math atom they are next.

Comment: @Seamus With `\operatorname` possibly `\newcommand{\Upd}{\operatorname{U}^{\operatorname{M}}}`.

Comment: @Seamus I updated my answer for all in upright font with argument while using `\DeclareMathOperator` as initially asked.

Answer (score 6):

Unlike `\newcommand`, `\DeclareMathOperator` does not have arguments.  If you need arguments, use `\newcommand`.  If you want U in your example to look like an operator, you can use a handy command `\operatorname` provided by `amsmath`.  Also, it is a good idea to use `\ensuremath` in the definition, so your operator can work inside text too.

This leads to the following solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\Upd}[1]{\ensuremath{\operatorname{U_M^{#1}}}}
\begin{document}
  $\Upd{a} (x)$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's not a good idea, in my opinion, to add `\ensuremath`; why should it be? Disclaimer: this is part of my `\ensuremath`-only-when-really-needed campaign. :)

Comment: You might be right :)