# renewcommand pendant for DefineMathOperator

Tags: math-operators

I'd like to change the definition of one of the predefined math operators (`\hom`).

Is there an equivalent to the `\renewcommand` statement for operators?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Comment: What do you want to change?

Comment: I need the \hom to be uppercase as it seems to be more usual to have "Hom" in german math documents.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not aware of any pendant, but you can use `\DeclareMathOperator` (not `\DefineMathOperator`) a second time if you mark the macro as not defined first.
However, changing it doesn't make that much sense, because such a math operator is only there to print the operator name in the correct font. You shouldn't add code or arguments to it. See [\DeclareMathOperator won't take arguments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34818/declaremathoperator-wont-take-arguments) for more about that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\let\hom\relax% Set equal to \relax so that LaTeX thinks it's not defined
\DeclareMathOperator{\hom}{HOM}

\begin{document}

$\hom$

\end{document}
```