# newcommand vs. DeclareMathOperator

Tags: macros, math-operators

As far as I understand, whatever can be done using `DeclareMathOperator` can also be achieved using `newcommand`, but not the other way around. If this is the case, what are the circumstances where `DeclareMathOperator` is the better choice? When should I take solely `newcommand`?

I found a question regarding [arguments and `DeclareMathOperator`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34818/412), and I wonder what other aspects should be taken into consideration when it comes to choosing which method to use when defining math operators.

Comment: Run `texdoc amsmath` and see page 13f.

Comment: `\DeclareMathOperator` is a very special case of `\newcommand`, so the question as it stands is too generic to receive an answer.

Comment: Sort of related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/655/86 I'd go for the "horses for courses" argument: `\DeclareMathOperator` says what it's going to do and does it, so makes it easier for you to remember 6months later what it was meant for.  Also, if you want a consistent look you're going to effectively reimplement `\DeclareMathOperator` (*this* `\newcommand` should produce the same effect as *that* `\newcommand` but not *the other* `\newcommand` so we'd better have a "helper" macro for *this* and *that* but not *the other*) so why not take advantage of the work others have already done?

Comment: Consider \newcommand{\im}{\text{im}} with \DeclareMathOperator{\im}{im}. Now try and use these commands in the standard theorem environment. In the former "im" will be italicized, but in the latter "im" won't be.

Comment: is this in the `amsmath` package?

Comment: `\ DeclareMathOperator` is defined in `amsopn` which is loaded by default when including `amsmath`.

Comment: @user2154420 I've defined operators in bold and when I type them in proofs they're not italicized but in theorem environment they are, any idea on how to never have them in italic?

Answer (score 236, accepted):

`\DeclareMathOperator` is designed to create commands that should typeset operator names such as `sin` and `lim`.  Some of these are already defined in base TeX or LaTeX so one writes `2\sin\theta`

[image: op sine]

instead of `2sin\theta`

[image: nop sine]

giving correct spacing and font.  If you need an operator of this type that is not predefined, then you create it with `\DeclareMathOperator`, e.g. the space of endomorphisms of a vector space is written `\End V`

[image]

but you need to make the definition `\DeclareMathOperator{\End}{End}` first: a minimal working example is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\End}{End}
\begin{document}

\( \End V \)

\end{document}
```

`\newcommand` is much more general and can be used to define direct short cuts or more complicated macros.  So for example if you find youself writing `\left.\frac d{dt}\right|_{t=0}` many times in your document you can package this up as a single command `\dtzero` via `\newcommand{\dtzero}{\left.\frac d{dt}\right|_{t=0}}` and just type `\dtzero` each time instead.

I would usually recommend reserving `\DeclareMathOperator` for the use described above and using `\newcommand` in most other situations.  To get the effect of `\DeclareMathOperator` in a one-off situation, or inside a `\newcommand`, you use `\operatorname`; so you can write `\operatorname{End}V` for the above example.

Finally, one should note that there is a starred version `\DeclareMathOperator*`.  This is used for defining operators that have limits typeset beneath them instead of to the right (at least when in a display).  For example

[image: Sample output]

Similarly there is the starred variant `\operatorname*`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\End}{End}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\Max}{Max}
\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
  \Max_{x\in A} f(x) \qquad  \End_R V 
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

*Remark.*  The above code samples load the `amsmath` package.  Strictly speaking all you need is the `amsopn` package, which `amsmath` reads in automatically. Alternatively, one can load `mathtools` which is a modern package building further on `amsmath`.

Comment: Many thanks for the comments and the kind welcome.  I have edited my answer to make the example slightly more realistic using `\boldsymbol` instead.

Comment: @egreg and Barbara Beeton: I have now put in a different example without this bold symbol issue.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: the bm versus boldsymbol issue was tackled in http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3238

Comment: It is worth to mention that there is also a starred version of \operatorname.

Comment: @Rauni OK - now added.

Answer (score 43):

I usually use

```
\newcommand{\Ker}{\operatorname{Ker}}
```

instead of

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\Ker}{Ker}
```

However, the second is much practical.

Comment: Nice because it allows to do `\renewcommand`, and I don't know what is the equivalent for `DeclareMathOperator`.

Comment: You can first "undefine" the command by `\let`ting it be equal to `\relax`, e.g., `\let\div\relax \DeclareMathOperator{\div}{div}`.

Comment: `\operatorname` is still superior because you may `\providecommand` for conditional `\renewcommand`, of course you can use an `\if \fi` construct, but that somewhat defeats the purpose of LaTeX vs TeX.

Comment: @MSC Why does everything in $\LaTeX$ have to be so unbelievably hacky…

Answer (score 11):

Another difference is that `\DeclareMathOperator` can only be used in the preamble while `\newcommand` has no such restriction.

Comment: Does anyone know why that is?

Comment: All `\Declare...` commands share the property. See Dox's answer, though.

Answer (score 2):

Another advantage that I have seen in using `\newcommand` instead of `\DeclareMathOperator` is that by adding `\ensuremath{}` to `\newcommand`, we can use it easily in between text.

E.g. `\newcommand{\w}{\ensuremath{\mathbf{w}}\xspace}`. You can simply use `\w` in text mode without adding `$` on either side to get a math bold w. `\xspace` is added to add space after the use of the command, as required.

Comment: Just an observation about the use of `\xspace`: [Drawbacks of xspace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86620)