# Macros for image, coimage, and cokernel

Tags: macros

I work in LyX. There's a default macro for the kernel: `\ker` which has nice spacing if I put something after it, compared to `\text{ker}`. I'd like to have macros with the same nice spacing for the image, coimage, and cokernel, respectively `im, coim, coker`.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67506/newcommand-vs-declaremathoperator

Comment: And please avoid `co<...>` terms if it is possible to mention it otherwise. It's pretty much a jargon for let say matrices and many other linear operators.

Comment: @percusse, I don't understand. I want these macros for notes on category theory.

Comment: @Exterior Nevermind then :)

Comment: @percusse why do you say avoid "co" expressions?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Because most of the time with exceptions such as category theory, it is possible to just say ker(A') etc. depending on the operator. `co<...>` adds yet another layer of difficulty on the nonmathematician reader though the underlying idea remains unchanged.

Comment: @percusse who cares about nonmathematician readers? ;-)

Comment: One could endeavor to refrain from using "co" even in category theory by continually switching between opposite categories :p

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Hence my comment "Nevermind then" :P