# Conditional spacing on \renewcommand

Tags: macros

I have a considerable amount of TeX documents that will be displayed on a website. The problem is, for this specific set of users, trigonometric functions such as `\tan{x}` are spelled differently - `tg x` in that case.

So, I approached this issue knowing the following LaTeX command

`\providecommand{\tan}{}\renewcommand{\tan}{\hspace{2pt}\mathrm{tg\,}}`

Including `\,` is necessary to render `\tan{2x}` as `tg 2x`. However, such addition causes `\tan(2x)` to be rendered with an unnecessary space before the argument: `tg (2x)`

How could I conditionally include that `\,` based on the presence of curly brackets?

Comment: As always mathjax is off topic on this site. You will need to ask your question elsewhere. (mathjax does not use latex anywhere)

Comment: I'm sorry for the inconvenience. I thought tex.stackexchange would regard anything TeX related... Anyway, I will reformulate my question, as the same problem can be observed in LaTeX.

Comment: What you need is an operator. Search how to define new math operators.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67506/newcommand-vs-declaremathoperator; you'll need to `\let\tan\undefined`.

Comment: mathjax is not even tex related (as such), it is just a javascript library who can understand a subset of the latex syntax. Redefinition is a good idea if you want to know how to do this in LaTeX, just remember that it might not apply to mathjax afterwards

Comment: Defining a new math operator worked for me. All the rapid feedback the community gave to my question was much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: you do not need to use explicit spacing and fonts, mathjax supporrts `\DeclareMathOperator ` from amsmath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Sigur stated, the desired behavior is achieved by defining a new math operator. The following command worked as expected:

`\providecommand{\tan}{}\renewcommand{\tan}{\mathop{\rm tg}\nolimits}`

---

There's a better, cleaner and more straightforward solution, pointed by David Carlisle: `\DeclareMathOperator \tan{tg}`

Comment: better to use `\DeclareMathOperator \tan{tg}`