# Custom function stopped working for no reason

Tags: errors

I defined an operator

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\s2}{s_{2}}
```

And the second time I use it, it tells me "!Use of \s doesn't match its definition.  \s 2..."
In another instance of the document, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: I don't think you can have numbers in your command name. LaTeX has certain rules about what constitutes a macro name and `\s2` won't work. Try `\stwo` or `\sii` instead. Or even better, define a macro with an argument. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9718/35864

Comment: But it already worked once and is still continuing to work in the first instance despite the failure in the second instance, so I can actually have numbers in the command name.

Comment: One-digit names like `\0` to `\9` work, but letter-digit combinations won't. Depending on what exactly you did maybe it only worked by accident. Can you shows an example of the macro that worked, please?

Comment: Okay, so it literally works with s3 for any number of times, but not s2, and s3 uses the exact same format.

Comment: Ah, I think I see what is going on. I'd have to confirm this, but here goes. When you write `\DeclareMathOperator{\s2}{s_{2}}` you define a delimited macro `\s` that must always be followed by `2` to be complete. You then can't use `\s` without a trailing `2`. If you try to use `\s3` it breaks because there is no `2`. I feel the solution is to define a macro with an argument.

Comment: You say that if I try to use \s3 it breaks, but \s3 is the one that fully functions.

Comment: No I say that you can have exactly one of `\s1`, `\s2`, ... `\s9` working. When you have several `\DeclareMathOperator{\s...}` the one defined last should be the only one that works.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66671/35864

Comment: Okay that makes sense then. So the argument is obviously going to change a lot for such a vague operator, I don't want to limit any particular version to just one argument. Is there a more efficient way to overcome that issue?

Comment: Define a command with an argument, see for example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34818/35864. If it were me I'd probably just say `\DeclareMathOperator{\s}{s}` and write `s_1` later. If you must have the subscript in the command name use something like `\sii` instead of `\s2`.

Comment: That's grossly impractical because then I would end up having siiiiiiiiiiiii which is going to look unprofessional to anyone who reviews the document. Why wouldn't LaTex just let the authors notate their operators as they want? What could possibly be the harm in using an additional number or two?

Comment: Obviously that would be `\sxiii`, but I see what you are getting at. It is, however, also impractical to define thirteen or more macros with almost the same definition that only differ in the subscript. In that case a macro with argument seems the way to go. There are ways around this (see my first link), but they do have their disadvantages.

Answer (score 1):

As you can't have digits in command names normally, one option is to declare a command that accepts one additional number argument that is used internally as part of the command name:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\s}[1]{\csname s#1\endcsname}
\newcommand{\declareS}[2]{%
    \expandafter\DeclareMathOperator
    \expandafter{\csname s#1\endcsname}{#2}%
}

\declareS1{s_{1}}
\declareS2{s_{2}}
\declareS{30}{s_{30}}

\begin{document}

$\s1(t) + \s2(t) > \s{30}(t)$

\end{document}
```

This defines a new command `\s` which requires one argument and then calls a command `\sXX`, where `XX` is the argument. To define the called command, you use `\declareS` which takes the same `XX` as first parameter and as second parameter the body of `\DeclareMathOperator`.

Make sure to use braces for the number argument if it is longer than a single digit. The `\declareS` command is also very limited, it always declares an `\s...` command and always maps it to a math operator. Adding extra parameters to make it more general is possible, of course.